# Changing Git Repo

Tags: git, github

My repo was taken down off GitHub for a copyright infringement. I have since removed all the files that were an issue and want to get it back into GitHub. I am assuming I need to push it to a new repo. I am not sure exactly how to go about making the switch. Can anyone explain how this might be accomplished?

When trying to push it with a `git push origin master`

I get:

```
remote: Repository unavailable due to DMCA takedown.
remote: See the takedown notice for more details:
remote: <link to the take down>
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<repo>': The requested URL returned error: 503
```

Comment: You should consider moving from github/microsoft. It is unsafe to rely on this guys

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new repository. You need to add a `remote` repository.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Then you should see this `remote` when run:

```
git remote -v
```

Check [here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote) for more details.

Comment: So I ran that command with a different repo name, and I get the following: fatal: remote origin already exists. Any ideas?

Comment: When I run `git remote -v` it still shows the old origin. Do I need to remove the old origin first?

Comment: You need to remove your old `origin`: `git remote rm origin` and then do this. `origin` is basically the short-hand name of your remote repository on Github. You can call it anything you like really.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch repos, you need to change your git remotes.

You can view your current remote by changing into your repo and running `git remote -v`, which gives you the name and the repo path:

```
origin  git@github.com:username/reponame.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:username/reponame.git (push)
```

You can delete this old origin via `git remote remove origin` and add a new one with `git remote add origin git@github.com:username/newreponame.git`.

Don't forget that removing files from your repo may not be enough; you'll have to [purge them from your Git history](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data).